# iOS 10 - Local Notification actions not visible after swiping right to left and selecting the 'View' button

Tags: ios, notifications, xamarin.ios

I understand that with the new iOS 10, for Non-Force Touch devices, when the application is in the background, after swiping from right to left, you only see two options : View and Clear.

When I open the notification center however, and select the View option, I only see the alert, minus the action buttons beneath it. If I select view for other apps on my phone, I'm able to see the alert, along with the action buttons below it, if any.

The action buttons are visible when the app is in the foreground. Is there a setting that needs to be enabled in code?

Below is how I implemented the `WillPresentNotification` function.

```
public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        try
        {

            // Do something with the notification
            Console.WriteLine("Active Notification: {0}", notification);
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert|UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }
    }
```